# Loop JavaScript between XMLHttpRequest start and end

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to perform an AJAX request that can can take some time using **plain old Javascript (not jQuery)**.  The request calls an endpoint that processes some transactions.

I can check on the status of the transaction via another endpoint, but I was hoping to 'refresh' this information on screen whilst the async AJAX request is taking place.  This 'progress' transaction will also be a GET AJAX request.

I have been looking at the XmlHttpRequest object and have attempted to use `onprogress`, but this doesn't really do anything like what I'm expecting, which is sort of a `while` loop.

In pseudo code, this would be

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'process/', true);
    xhr.send();

    // while request is pending, call another process repeatedly

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log("Request Successful");
            } else {
                console.log("Request Failed");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Request State changed but not complete");
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to crack this.  I was assuming a while loop depending on a suitably scoped value might do the trick, but it doesn't seem like the async aspect ever updates this value to break the loop.

I assumed this might be quite common, for progress bars etc, but I can't find anything viable?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: My guess is that you would have to use a `setInterval` that initiates & completes a separate XHR just to report the progress, while your first XHR is still "working". Maybe wrap it all in a function that you could pass a callback to.

Comment: @dmitrydwhite thanks - I managed to get it working not long after posting.  I've added the snippet below in case it helps anyone else, although I'm open to the fact that it might not be the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

In typical fashion, I figured this out not long after posting.

I set the function to call every second, and then removed the interval after the request completed:

```
    let intervalId;
    xhr.onloadstart = function (e) {
        intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            myProgressFunction();
        }, 1000)
    };
    xhr.open('GET', '/process', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onloadend = function (e) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
```